# jxls #VALUE! error with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, jxls

I am getting `#VALUE! error` for a cell containing this formula in Excel:

```
VLOOKUP(O14;Sheet2.A1:AL1000;HLOOKUP(K14;Sheet2.A2:AL3;2;0);1)
```

I am using an Excel sheet as a template and I'm generating my Excel file using `jxls`. When I open the generated file in Excel I get the `#VALUE! error.`
If I then update the cell without any change (F2 + Enter) it shows the proper value.

How can I see the correct value just opening the file?

Comment: that syntax looks all wrong to me... should it not be: `VLOOKUP(O14,Sheet2!A1:AL1000,HLOOKUP(K14,Sheet2!A2:AL3,2,0),1)` (with `,` in place of your `;` and `!` in place of your `.`)?

Comment: `1` Are you using the Dutch version of Excel? If not then What is your regional setting? `2` Is Calculation Set to Automatic?

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you should use the formula like this:

```
$[VLOOKUP(O14;Sheet2.A1:AL1000;HLOOKUP(K14;Sheet2.A2:AL3;2;0);1)]
```

Then jXLS will evaluate correctly.

Or you can use the `setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` method from the POI Sheet object (HSSFSheet, XSSFSheet, and so on...). This will force all formulas to be recalculated when the workbook is opened.